# remove_action from a plugin class on a different namespace

Tags: wordpress

Good evening to all, i've a little problem removing an action from wp_head that was added by Wordpress Download Manager. That's the code from the plugin:

```js
class WordPressDownloadManager{

    function __construct(){

        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'Install'));

        add_action( 'init', array($this, 'registerPostTypeTaxonomy'), 1 );

        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array($this, 'loadTextdomain') );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'EnqueueScripts') );

        add_action( 'wp_head', array($this, 'wpHead') );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array($this, 'wpFooter') );

        spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'AutoLoad' ) );

        new \WPDM\libs\UserDashboard();
        new \WPDM\libs\Apply();
        new \WPDM\admin\WordPressDownloadManagerAdmin();
        new \WPDM\ShortCodes();

    }
```

and this is the code i'm using to remove it:

```js
function remove_wpdm() {
  remove_action('wp_head', array('WordPressDownloadManager', 'wpHead'));
}
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_wpdm');
```

without effects.. How can i solve this? this class is in a different namespace called WPDM. Thank you in advance for any help.

Best regards,
Domenico

Comment: Why you are not putting this code in comment : add_action( 'wp_head', array($this, 'wpHead') );

Comment: @user8262086 I saw that documentation before and i thought that it was right to use `remove_action('wp_head', array('WordPressDownloadManager', 'wpHead'));` but it's not working... i do not have a global class to call, so i had to use that method.. maybe a priority issue? i tried with higher priorities without any effect. Thank you

Comment: @AkshayShah 'cause i want to enable this code on a single specific page.. The code it's needed for the plugin to work but it isn't necessary on pages that do not use it..

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
function remove_wpdm() {
  remove_action('wp_head', array('WordPressDownloadManager', 'wpHead'));
}
add_action('init', 'remove_wpdm');
```